# Sort the contents of an array from the values of an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

i have an array and an arraylist:

```
String[] league = {"Leeds United","Liverpool","Chelsea","Manchester City","Stoke City"...
List<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
points.add(7);
poinst.add(0);
points.add(5);
points.add(0);
points.add(5);
```

where :

leeds united = 7

liverpool = 0
etc...

i want to be able to sort the list to be in descending numerical order but the league array should reflect this sort.

is this possible? and how would i do it.
thanks

Comment: Can you change the code to use class structure? with club name and point as member?

Answer (score 2):

Define this static class somewhere:

```
private static final class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    private final String name;
    private final int score;
    private Pair(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair p2) {
        return Integer.compare(p2.score, score);
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return "["+score+":"+name+"]";
    }
}
```

and fill a list of Pairs from your score data and sort it:

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<league.length;++i)
    pairs.add(new Pair(league[i], points.get(i)));
Collections.sort(pairs);

System.out.println(pairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the correct storage format to achieve this**

First of all you should use an `Map`

`Maps` are designed to store a relation from a key to a specific value, in your case from String to int (`Map<String, Integer>`)

**You can then sort the `Map` like described in this question:**

[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

That should be the most adequate solution to your problem.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, can you please specify what you think is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

This uses Java's `Comparator` interface and stores the points in a map according to the array:

```
final Map<String, Integer> pointMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < league.length; i++) {
    pointMap.put(league[i], points.get(i));
}

Collections.sort(league, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return Integer.compare(pointMap.get(b), pointMap.get(a)); //descending order
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, sorry! I've forgot to get the according integer from the list. Please remove the down-vote or add a comment explaining why the downvote was done and how to improve the answer.

Comment: how would i use the comparator? sorry i have no experience with it

Answer (score 0):

First you need an associative data structure to hold clubs and its point. A Map sounds like a proper choice.

```
// Key is club, value is its point
final Map<String, Integer> points = ...
```

Then you can sort your league array by descending point order using a custom comparator

```
Arrays.sort(league, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String club1, String club2) {
    return -Integer.compare(points.get(club1), points.get(club2));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this problem would be to create an object abstraction of your data which implements `Comparable`, create instances of those, and sort them in the list with `Collections.sort`.

```
    public class FootballClub implements Comparable<FootballClub> {
        private final int rank;
        private String name;

        public FootballClub(final int rank, final String name) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int compareTo(final FootballClub other) {
            return rank - other.getRank();
        }
    }
```

Using an array and an `ArrayList` here makes no sense.  Use the data structures that will benefit you the most.

Comment: footballClubs.put(0, ""Leeds United"); footballClubs.put(0, "Liverpool"); - will update the existing item. does not solve the issue.

Comment: It's covered by other answers, so I'll vary mine a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the self-contained Java (5+) solution with complexity N Log N:

```
    assert league.length == points.size() : "arrays must have the same size";
    //fill a map
    final Map<String,Integer> teamPoints = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < league.length; i++) {
        teamPoints.put(league[i], points.get(i));
    }
    //sort
    Arrays.sort(league, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            //sort in descending order
            return teamPoints.get(o2) - teamPoints.get(o1);
        }

    });
```